# Discrete Math Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers with $k\leq n$.  Find the number of permutations of $\{1,2,…,n\}$ in which $\{1, 2,…,k\}$ appears as a subsequence but $\{1, 2,…,k,k+1\}$ does not

for example, if $k = 2$,

$$1 2 3$$  Does not work since $3$ appears right after $k-1$
$$1 3 2$$
$$2 1 3$$
$$2 3 1$$
$3 1 2$ Only $3 1 2$ works but I don't know why

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematics SE Kaylee.It is very helpful to know what trials and errors you have made. This way we can better assess your capabilities and act accordingly. Ergo "What have you tried?"If you don't do so, most probably questions get closed here, I.e. no answers can be added. Since you are new user, I am not voting to close this question. But be sure to add your effort unless this question will be closed later.

Comment: Folks, please don't downvote and discourage a new user just because the don't know how this website works.Give them some time to understand.

Comment: I dont understand your examples. First of all, they should be on separate lines...

Answer (score 0):

Since the first $k$ elements are fixed you need only choose $n-k$ from $n$. Since the question asks for permutations, order matters, so you must multiply by $(n-k)!$. The result: $n!/k!$.

Answer (score 0):

First count the number of permutations that have $1,2,\dots,k$ as a subsequence. We can do this by considering $1,2,\dots,k$ as one group and permute that with the remaining $n-k$ elements. Thus we are permuting a total of $n-k+1$ objects which can be done in $(n-k+1)!$ ways.

Next, we subtract off the number of permutations that have $1,2,\dots,k+1$ as a subsequence. Using a similar analysis, this can be done in $(n-(k+1)+1)! = (n-k)!$ ways.

Thus, our final answer is $(n-k+1)! - (n-k)!$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a permutation of $\{k+1,\dots,n\}$: we have $(n-k)!$ of them.

There would be $n-k+1$ slots where to insert $1,2,\dots,k$ (including the left and right), but we cannot use one of these slots, the one at the left of $k+1$. Hence just $n-k$. So the final answer should be
$$
(n-k)\cdot(n-k)!
$$

For $n=3$ and $k=2$, we get indeed one.

Let's see the case $n=5$ and $k=2$. The permutations of $\{3,4,5\}$ are
$$
\color{red}{3},4,5 \qquad 
\color{red}{3},5,4 \qquad 
4,\color{red}{3},5\qquad
4,5,\color{red}{3} \qquad
5,\color{red}{3},4\qquad
5,4,\color{red}{3}
$$
Let's take the first and insert $1,2$ in the admissible slots: we get
$$
\color{red}{3},\color{green}{1,2},4,5\qquad 
\color{red}{3},4,\color{green}{1,2},5\qquad
\color{red}{3},4,5,\color{green}{1,2}
$$
From the third we get
$$
\color{green}{1,2},4,\color{red}{3},5\qquad 
4,\color{red}{3},\color{green}{1,2},5\qquad 
4,\color{red}{3},5,\color{green}{1,2}
$$
and so on.

Note that this requires $n>k$ and $k>0$. For $n=k$ we obviously have one admissible permutation.